# PageRank algorithm. Iterative approach.

Tags: probability, graph-theory, algorithms

Given we have 4 nodes: A, B, C, D. A -> B and A <- B, B -> C, C -> D, C -> A and C <- A, D->A. We know only the starting probability of C which is 1. If we start from node C, what are the probabilities of nodes after 3 iterations. How is that calculated?

NB. I have such instructions to calculate it:
1)  0 Step : Start from a page.
2)  Choose randomly a link to follow (the same chances to choose any link). 
3)  Attach a probability to each edge. Sum of the probabilities add to 1.
4) Go on, the same way as before, from the nodes that you are able to  get, repeat part 2 and 3.  Find out the probabilities, to get to the new nodes, from the starting page. Sum of  the probabilities add to 1.

I dont get at all the instructions. Which probabilities, attach to what. Maybe for someone it makes more sense/

Comment: Are you assuming that in each iteration it is equally as likely that you take any of the 'transitions' possible at each node (for example, if you are at A in some iteration then in the next iteration you will be at B with probability 1/2 or at C also with probability 1/2)?

Comment: Yes. Thats right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_n$ denote the node you are in after $n$ iterations with $X_0$ denoting the node you started from. Then using the [total rule of probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability),

$$p(X_n=A)=P_{AA}p(X_{n-1}=A)+P_{AB}p(X_{n-1}=B)+\dots+P_{AD}p(X_{n-1}=D)\quad (*)$$

where $P_{UV}:=p(X_n=U|X_{n-1}=V)$, that is the probability of transitioning in one iteration from a node $V$ to a node $U$. We can find similar expressions $p(X_n=B)$, $p(X_n=C)$ and $p(X_n=D)$.

Let $P$ denote the transition matrix (that is, the matrix whose $11$ entry is $P_{AA}$, $12$ entry is $P_{AB}$ and so on). In your case:

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&1\\\frac{1}{2}&0&0&0\\\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\0&0&\frac{1}{2}&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Let $p_n:=\begin{bmatrix}p(X_n=A)&p(X_n=B)&p(X_n=C)&p(X_n=D)\end{bmatrix}^T$. So in your case you want to compute $p_3$ and you are given that $p_0=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}^T$. Then we can rewrite $(*)$ (and the similar expressions for $p(X_n=B)$...) above as:

$$p_n=Tp_{n-1}$$

Hence,

$$p_3=Tp_2=T^2p_1=T^3p_0.$$

By the way, what you are looking at is called a Markov chain and a nice introductory course about them can be found [here](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rrw1/markov/).